# Draw multiple times from a single bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to draw a board which consists of 35 small blocks and each small block is similar but when I use a bitmap to draw multiple times i.e 35 times then it clears the previous drawn image. At the end there is only one image left.
So can anybody help me finding a solution for this.

Here is the code which I tried

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { Bitmap  empty=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.empty);
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
        canvas.drawBitmap(empty, curX, curY, null);
        curX +=blockWidth;
    }
    curY=curY+blockHeight;
     curX=0;
   }
  }
```

(curX->it keep track of the x coordinate and curY->keep track of y coordinate initial value of both curX and curY are 0, blockWeidth and blockHeight are constants with value 70px and 65px respectively)

Comment: add your code we are not magician!!!

Comment: This code looks fine, please paste the code where you're calling the onDraw method from.